# C# Selenium: Can't catch exception when using wait.Until

Tags: c#, selenium, try-catch

When using `wait.Until()` in a try / catch block, if the element isn't there it throws NoSuchElementException exception. However, when I try to catch the exception, I still get the error.

```
        try
        {
            wait.Until(el => el.FindElement(By.Id("courseTestItem")));
            driver.Close();
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
            Console.WriteLine("Skipped: " + courses[0].Item1.Text + " (Has test)");
        }
        catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException) { }
```

I even tried just using a `catch (Exception e) { }` and that still didn't catch the error.

[Image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjqXT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a try / catch use:

```
if (wait.Until(el => el.FindElements(By.Id("filterText"))).Count > 0) { }
else if (wait.Until(el => el.FindElements(By.Id("sp-search-results-search"))).Count > 0) { }
else System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

This checks to see if more than 0 elements matching the criteria is found, meaning that the element was found.

Thanks to u/Simmo7 on Reddit for the help.